# "I {may / might} have missed that information."

Tags: word-choice, past-perfect, subjunctives, spoken-english

I have confusion in below 2 statements.

> A) I **may** have missed that information.
>   B) I **might** have missed that information.

I wanted to say I possibly missed that information "in past" to someone.
So at that time **may** OR **might** which one should I use?

Comment: @user178049 - Do you have a reference for that?  Everything I've ever seen says [*may* can be used in the past tense](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/may-might-may-have-and-might-have).

Comment: You can use either one. It's the *have* that lets us know you're talking about past time.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the subjunctive or the past perfect  and those tags should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, both mean there was a "possibility" that you missed it

> I **may** have missed that information *(when they said it)*.
>   I **might** have missed that information *(when they said it)*.

Answer (score -1):

Though they are both correct, "I might have missed that information" is more correct. "Might" is better usage here because it happened in **the past.** Also, using "may" sounds a bit stiff and formal here. If anything, I'd recommend using "might".